# How can I move several draggables together?

Tags: flutter, draggable

I'm working on a game where I'd like to make it possible to stick multiple draggables together to make them movable together.
Is there a way to attach a draggable to another?

Comment: You just make it one `Draggable`?

Comment: It's a figure which consists of multiple draggables to make it possible to move it around on a grid of drag targets. Making it one draggable would be a workaround and would be complicated because the figure is bigger than the drag target and the drag targets which are covered by the figure should all be occupied.